# How should I use unique pointer in c++11 when the destructor is private?

Tags: c++11, unique-ptr

I'm managing the class whose destructor is private since the object must be assigned into heap.

Let's suppose this class as A.

```
 std::unique_ptr<A> a(new A());
```

When this a is out of scope, destructor is called.

However, the default behavior of unique_ptr is calling "public destructor".

In this case, how should I do without making the destructor public?

Comment: Try putting `friend std::unique_ptr<A>::deleter_type;` inside `A`

Comment: "must be assigned into heap" - If you mean, must be allocated on the heap, making the destructor private is not the best way. Make all constructors private and only allow object creation via factory functions that already return `unique_ptr`s. Otherwise the client has to deal with weird syntax on every use.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Unfortunately that's not portable. The deleter may well use a helper function that is not part of its class for the actual deletion, and then it will fail again.

Comment: @SebastianRedl Sure. Thanks you to provide me with a valuable comment. I tried to implement Helper function as pergy suggested.

Comment: @zurotic have you succeed? :)

Comment: @pergy yeah. thanks a lot:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may define a `deleter` functional and make it `friend` with your class.

```cpp
#include <memory>

class A{
    friend struct D;
private:
    ~A() {}
};
struct D {
    void operator()(A* a) const {
        delete a;
    }
};
int main(){
    std::unique_ptr<A, D> a(new A());
    return 0;
}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d1dacc7f85e6009)